# How to arrange html sentences having different structures

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have few hundreds of html files look like the below.

```
<nonDerivativeTable>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> #First Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Stock</value>
        </securityTitle>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> #Second Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <footnoteId id="F1"/>
        </securityTitle>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> #Third Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Option</value>
            <footnoteId id="F2"/>
            <footnoteId id="F3"/>
        </securityTitle>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
</nonDerivativeTable>
```

Two variables that I would like to extract is security ('Stock' in #First holding, '' in #Second holding, and 'Option' in #Third holding) and security_footnote ('' in #First holding, 'F1; F2' in #Second holding, and 'F3' in #Third holding. But securityTitle and securityTitleFootnote do not always exist.
Also, sometimes there are multiple footnote IDs just like in the #third holding.
I want to write each rwo using data in each "Holding" tag allowing for empty values.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'htmparser') #Let's say doc has the html.

    try:
        securityTitles = soup.select('securityTitle > value').text
    except:
        securitiyTitles = ''
    try: 
        securityTitleFootnotes = '; 'join(soup.select('securityTitle > footnoteid').get('id')
    except:
        securityTitleFootnotes = ''

    for securityTitle, securityTitleFootnote in zip(securitiyTitles, securityTitleFootnotes):
        writer.writerow([securityTitle, securityTitleFootnote])
```

I want the result to be

[Want Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEhkW.jpg)

Note: one of url that I am trying to parse is "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12927/0001225208-09-018738.txt". sentences that I uploaded are only part of the data.
Now I see that those are XML... rather than HTML.

Comment: That's XML, not HTML.

Comment: It surely is HTML. The tags and the sturctures that I uploaded are simplified version of what I have.

Comment: table is an html tag security/holding/footnoteid are not html tags.

Comment: I changed the tags into the original one.

Comment: Are you looking for an actual table (as in a pandas dataframe) which contains the title of the securities and related footnotes (if any), or something else?

Comment: No, what I want is just to create two variables which contain security titiles and corresponding footnotes respectively.

Comment: So you should clarify your question to say that explicitly. Also, are you looking for the footnote id or the actual footnote? If the first, the answer below gives you that. Also, some securities have more than one footnote - explain in the question how you want that handled in your expected output (and provide an example of that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the contents for each `nonDerivativeHolding`, and then apply a custom list of handlers for each:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
c = [i.securitytitle.contents for i in soup(s, 'html.parser').find_all('nonderivativeholding')]
h = [('value', lambda x:x.text), ('footnoteid', lambda x:x['id'])]
results = [[i for i in b if i != '\n'] for b in c]
r = [{a:(lambda x:'' if not x else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)([b(j) for j in i if j.name == a]) for a, b in h} for i in results]
```

Output:

```
[{'value': 'Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': '', 'footnoteid': 'F1'}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': ['F2', 'F3']}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. But one small problem is that the code requires quite amount of time to run it. Is there anyway to shorten the running time? It's because I have more than 0.1 million of htmls to go through.

Comment: @zerogravit Currently, this code is trying to format the results by ensuring that even unmatched keys are given an `''` as a value. If you just wanted to store the string results and not worry about paring them together, the speed could be increased a bit. Also, how are you accessing the HTML source? Are you sending a request to the pages, or is it simply a very large file on your local system?